# iOS application crashes with frequent image drawing to context

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a crash in my iOS application which uses CoreGraphics to work with images.

After some time I've came up with this piece of code:

```
  UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // fromcamera

  for (int i = 0; ; ++i) 
    {
    NSLog(@"----- Step %d ---------", i);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

    UIImage * image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

It crashes after 24-th cycle on my iPhone 5 (cannot attach to device directly - have to use XCode 4.6 which cannot debug iOS 7).

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you attach the crash report? You probably run out of memory and Zaph is right.

Comment: As I wrote before - cannot attach to device with iOS 7 using XCode 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum add an @autoreleasepool to the loop to temporaries are released:

```
for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"----- Step %d ---------", i);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

        UIImage * image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Also you are creating a new `image1` in each iteration of the loop but it is not being used.

Comment: Trying @autorelease pool right now (got there by myself;). This code doesn't do anything, just demonstrates the crash, so, yep, image1 is unused.

Comment: yep, autorelease pool helped. Could you explain, why this is happening? I assumed, that using ARC should not cause these kind of problem - as you said, image1 is unused, so why do I run out of memory? My idea is that I allocate memory faster, than it is deallocated. Am I correct here?

Comment: ARC and Objective-C runtime use an autorelease pool. Items put into the pool are reclaimed later, generally in run loop. In a tight loop that isn't happening. The @autoreleasepool scope releases items in the pool sooner. Even in the Apple frameworks things are auto-released, that is how many objects can be safely returned to a calling method. OK, that was a simplified explanation, please study more about the autorelease pool.